# Exclude results where two fields are not of certain values

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables which have some transactional stuff stored in them. There will be many records per `user_id` in each table. Table1 and Table2 have a one-to-one relationship with each other. I want to pull records from both tables, but I want to exclude records which have certain values in **both** tables. I don't care if they both don't have these values, or if just one does, but both tables should not have both values.

For example:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.type, t2.name
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON table.xid = table2.id
  WHERE t1.user_id = 100
  AND (t1.type != 'FOO' AND t2.name != 'BAR')
```

So `t1.type` is type `ENUM` with about 10 different options, and `t2.name` is also type `ENUM` with 2 options.

My expected results would look a little like:

```
1, FOO, YUM
2, BOO, BAR
3, BOO, YUM
```

But instead, all I'm getting is:

```
3, BOO, YUM
```

It appears to be filtering out all records which has 'FOO' as the type, and 'BAR' as the name.

(*We're using MySQL 5.1...*)

Comment: Your query looks good to me - can you include a quick dump of your table's data. Maybe there's something in there you're missing (e.g. are you sure they all have `t1.user_id = 100`?).

Comment: @Dominic Rodger: I respectfully disagree - see my answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question, you should change your query to use `OR`:

```
AND (t1.type != 'FOO' OR t2.name != 'BAR')
```

This is the same as

```
AND NOT (t1.type = 'FOO' AND t2.name = 'BAR')
```

and will remove all rows, where both conditions match.

Comment: Wow, amazing.  That was it! I can't understand why this works, but it's working, lol. Using AND NOT makes sense, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why the 'OR' thing works. Figures it was something simple though. Thanks so much!!

Comment: The `OR`-thing only finds rows, where **at least** one value does not match, so it removes rows where both match :)

Comment: Ahhhh, I gotcha. Makes sense now... I think the thing that kept confusing me were the "!=". It's like having a double-negative. Thank you for the explanation. :)

Comment: Brilliant answer, I never knew of the "AND NOT" syntax!